# gVim not having enviroment variables using oh-my-zsh

Tags: ubuntu, vim, zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

Background:

```
Ubuntu 14.10 x64
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct 20 2014 16:09:34)
Patch incluse: 1-273
Last oh-my-zsh version (master)
```

Problem:

If I run gVim from the command line (terminator for example) then enviroments variables exported in my `$HOME/.zshenv` are correctly set into gVim (`:echo $SOMETHINGDEFINEDINZSHENV` works, `:!echo $SOMETHINGDEFINEDINZSHENV` works also)
If I run gVim from the Ubuntu Icon then no enviroments variables defined in my `$HOME/.zshenv` are exported in gVim
I've set zsh as my default shell with `chsh`, every `echo $SHELL` inside and outside gVim prints `/bin/zsh`
I already tried setting `set shell=/bin/zsh` or `set shell=/bin/sh`

Does anyone have any hints about this?

Comment: Someone voted to close this since it's not a programming question, but questions about programming tools ARE on-topic on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

When you start `gvim` in the terminal it inherits the evironment from the `zsh` running there. This `zsh` session got its own environment from the terminal it runs in and the settings in your `~/.zshenv`. The terminal in turn got its environment from the process that started it plus some own settings (e.g. `TERM`). And so on…

If you start `gvim` from its icon, it inherits the environment from your window manager (Unity?) as it is started by the WM. The WM got its environment from X (and maybe some own settings). As none of these processes are (usually) started by a `zsh` instance, the settings from `~/.zshenv` are never loaded.

If you want to set environment variables for all of your user's processes, you should do so in `~/.pam_environment` (`/etc/environment` for all users). Variables in there are set on login and will then be inherited by other processes started after, including your window manager. `~/pam_environment` should only be a list of `KEY=VALUE` statements (that is, `export` is not needed and will probably lead to errors).